# How to use _Layout.cshtml in View when application is Razor Pages

Tags: model-view-controller, navigationbar, razor-pages

In Razor Pages, the _Layout.chstml, is included by default (for all I know there is a setting somewhere). If you don't want the _Layout template on a Razor Page you put:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

However, on an MVC View, you reference a _Layout.chstml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ThankYou";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I'm not even sure the same _Layout can be used. I am hoping so and that I just don't have the route syntax for Views inside a Razor Pages application (.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages).

I tried:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ThankYou";
    Layout = "/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

But it triggered a Not Found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use the Razor Pages layout in an MVC View, use the virtual file path just like in your MVC example:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ThankYou";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Incidentally, the "setting" for the layout page in a Razor Pages application is in the [_ViewStart.cshtml file](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/viewstart). the default version includes the following content:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Comment: In my _Layout page I get a null reference error on the line that references RouteData: "var pageRoute = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"].ToString();"
So, I will accept your answer but I gotta figure out how to get around no RouteData.

Comment: RouteData exists, but the `page` value is only relevant to Razor Pages. It doesn't exist in MVC views.

Comment: I figured out how to catch the null reference problem. I am changing container class to fluid for 2 pages that have really wide tables. I am using this check:

                    var pageRoute = "";

                    if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"]==null)
                    {
                        //LEAVE pageRoute ALONE
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pageRoute = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"].ToString();
                    }